# Ошибка при заполнении массива Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здраствуйте. При заполнении массива данными выдается ошибка: 'list assignment index out of range'.

```
inp = 1
i = 0
a = []
while inp != 0:
inp = float(input("Введите число: "))
a[i] = inp
i = i + 1
print(sorted(a))
```

Comment: Добавление элемента в список происходит через метод `append`, просто так обратиться к любому `a[i]` нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Начальная длина списка нулевая, к нему нужно добавлять элементы

```
inp = float(input("Введите число: "))
a.append(inp)
```