# Несколько вводов в зависимости от переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x

у меня есть переменная, скажем
N = int(input())
как сделать так чтобы вторая переменная, которая использовала бы ввод пользователя, повторялась столько раз, сколько я ввел N
то есть если N = 5, то программа делает еще 5 вводов, если N = 7, то семь

Comment: с помощью цикла for

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы эти значения где-то сохранялись?

Comment: [добавлять](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/953076/Ошибка-при-заполнении-массива-python) их к списку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
N = int(input())

data = [input() for _ in range(N)]

print(data)
```

В переменной `data` будет список всех введённых пользователем значений

Answer (score 1):

Любое количество input() - выход пустая строка или не int()

```
N = []
while True:
    try:
        N.append(int(input()))
    except ValueError:
        break
print(N)
```